# Why height of RelativeLayout change when I add a view to RelativeLayout.

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I'm drawing lines in relative Layout.To do this, I add line views add to relative layout. But when I add drawed lines to relative layouts the Relative Layout's height changes. Why ? Thanks in advance for your help ! :)

**layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context="com.mobisoft.kelimebul.Local.Oyun"
    android:backgroundTint="#ffffcd8d"
    android:backgroundTintMode="multiply"
    android:background="#ffff9f63"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:id="@+id/s"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="true"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <GridView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/gameBoard"

            android:listSelector="#00000000"
            android:background="@color/tahta_rengi"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="false"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:background="@color/tahta_rengi"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scrolinear">

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/backgroundColorTint"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/timeIcon"
                    android:src="@drawable/clock"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginRight="4dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:id="@+id/time"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center|right|center_horizontal"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/score_textsize"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="@string/RemainingWordN"
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/score_textsize" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:id="@+id/remainingNumber"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/score_textsize" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity.java   // Some part code of this activity**

```
     DrawView drawView;
drawView = new DrawView(getApplicationContext(), locs, view.getWidth(), colors.get(lineColor));

                            RelativeLayoutOfLines.addView(drawView); // Add view to relativeLayouts
```

**DrawView.java**

```
public class DrawView extends View {
Paint paint = new Paint();
float locs[];
int strokeWidth;
int color;

public DrawView(Context context, float locs[], int strokeWidth, int color) {
    super(context);
    this.locs = locs;
    this.strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
    this.color = color;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    paint.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(color));
    paint.setAlpha(100);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);


    canvas.drawLine(locs[0], locs[1], locs[2], locs[3], paint);  // left, top, right, bottom

    canvas.save();
    canvas.restore();

}

}
```

Before Drawing: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/oo79d8rvp4sa2nj/s.PNG?dl=0

After Drawing :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vawjsxcbi6gd2go/s2.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Better show what's happening in screenshots.

Comment: I update my question ........

Comment: Is it because the height is set to wrap content? Everytime you throw another view into it and it will adjust the height.

Comment: okey. I solved my problem. I set weight of relative layout to 1. And I removed other weights. Even so thanks :)